# How to set a variable to store a value returned by select statement and perform an operation in stored procedure MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

1. Operation should perform according to value passed through parameter
2. A value should be returned using SELECT statement to a variable
3. Perform any operation and assign it to another variable.
4. UPDATE table using new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DepositToAcct`(ACC_NUM BIGINT,DEP_AMNT DOUBLE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE OLD_BAL DOUBLE;
    DECLARE NEW_BAL DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT BALANCE  INTO OLD_BAL 
    FROM account_details WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER= ACC_NUM;

    SET NEW_BAL = OLD_BAL+DEP_AMNT;

    UPDATE account_details 
    SET BALANCE=NEW_BAL 
    WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER= ACC_NUM;
END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).